# setting up 48 hour window for php booking system

Tags: php

I need some help at the moment with a booking system I'm developing.

I am trying to incorporate a 48 hour difference in all books made.

For example if a customer logs on to make a booking on 14/09/2011 03:28.

The system would only allow him to book from 16/09/2011 onwards.

Not only this but I want the system to only display dates in a certain year.

So the customer logging in on 14/09/2011 would only see dates from September to December. 2011 and not anything before or beyond that!

**How do I set up a 48 hour window for all bookings (i.e. +48 hours) and set a cut off date of the end of the year?**

Would appreciate any help.

Many thanks in advance!

```
<label for="date"><?php echo __('Pickup Date') ?> <span>*</span></label>
    <select name="day">
      <option value="1"   > 01 </option>
      <option value="2"   > 02 </option>
      <option value="3"   > 03 </option>
      <option value="4"   > 04 </option>
      <option value="5"   > 05 </option>
      <option value="6"   > 06 </option>
      <option value="7"   > 07 </option>
      <option value="8"   > 08 </option>
      <option value="9"   > 09 </option>
      <option value="10"   > 10 </option>
      <option value="11"   > 11 </option>
      <option value="12"   > 12 </option>
      <option value="13"   > 13 </option>
      <option value="14"   > 14 </option>
      <option value="15"   > 15 </option>
      <option value="16"   > 16 </option>
      <option value="17"   > 17 </option>
      <option value="18"   > 18 </option>
      <option value="19"   > 19 </option>
      <option value="20"   > 20 </option>
      <option value="21"   > 21 </option>
      <option value="22"   > 22 </option>
      <option value="23"   > 23 </option>
      <option value="24"   > 24 </option>
      <option value="25"   > 25 </option>
      <option value="26"   > 26 </option>
      <option value="27"   > 27 </option>
      <option value="28"   > 28 </option>
      <option value="29"   > 29 </option>
      <option value="30"   > 30 </option>
      <option value="31"   > 31 </option>
    </select>
    </select>
    &nbsp;:&nbsp;
    <select name="monthyear">
      <option value="January <?php echo date("Y"); ?>">January <?php echo date("Y"); ?></option>
      <option value="February <?php echo date("Y"); ?>">February <?php echo date("Y"); ?></option>
      <option value="March <?php echo date("Y"); ?>">March <?php echo date("Y"); ?></option>
      <option value="April <?php echo date("Y"); ?>">April <?php echo date("Y"); ?></option>
      <option value="May <?php echo date("Y"); ?>">May <?php echo date("Y"); ?></option>
      <option value="June <?php echo date("Y"); ?>">June <?php echo date("Y"); ?></option>
      <option value="July <?php echo date("Y"); ?>">July <?php echo date("Y"); ?></option>
      <option value="August <?php echo date("Y"); ?>">August <?php echo date("Y"); ?></option>
      <option value="September <?php echo date("Y"); ?>">September <?php echo date("Y"); ?></option>
      <option value="October <?php echo date("Y"); ?>">October <?php echo date("Y"); ?></option>
      <option value="November <?php echo date("Y"); ?>">November <?php echo date("Y"); ?></option>
      <option value="December <?php echo date("Y"); ?>">December <?php echo date("Y"); ?></option>
    </select><p>
    <label for="time"><?php echo __('Pickup Time') ?> <span>*</span></label>
    <select name="hour">
      <option value="00"  >00</option>
      <option value="01"  >01</option>
      <option value="02"  >02</option>
      <option value="03"  >03</option>
      <option value="04"  >04</option>
      <option value="05"  >05</option>
      <option value="06"  >06</option>
      <option value="07"  >07</option>
      <option value="08"  >08</option>
      <option value="09"  >09</option>
      <option value="10"  >10</option>
      <option value="11"  >11</option>
      <option value="12"  >12</option>
      <option value="13"  >13</option>
      <option value="14"  >14</option>
      <option value="15"  >15</option>
      <option value="16"  >16</option>
      <option value="17"  >17</option>
      <option value="18"  >18</option>
      <option value="19"  >19</option>
      <option value="20"  >20</option>
      <option value="21"  >21</option>
      <option value="22"  >22</option>
      <option value="23"  >23</option>
    </select>
    &nbsp;:&nbsp;
    <select name="minutes">
      <option value="00"  >00</option>
      <option value="05"  >05</option>
      <option value="10"  >10</option>
      <option value="15"  >15</option>
      <option value="20"  >20</option>
      <option value="25"  >25</option>
      <option value="30"  >30</option>
      <option value="35"  >35</option>
      <option value="40"  >40</option>
      <option value="45"  >45</option>
      <option value="50"  >50</option>
      <option value="55"  >55</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What about that massive wall of code isn't working for you? What is the actual problem you're facing?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I've updated it

Answer (score 0):

Your situation needs clarification. I think I understand what you want, but it would help if you refined your post down to a single question instead of your project requirements, such as "How do I update my  based on the user's booking date?" I apologize if you know that already.

If you want the  to reflect the pickup date, then you will need to incorporate the HTML rendering within your PHP code. Basically, you'll need to use the PHP functions echo() or print() along with a control structure (if / loop) to send the appropriate  tags to the DOM.